# Python retrieve RUID?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

I am using a version of python prior to 2.7 on linux and was wondering how to retrieve the RUID?

2.7 and later have getresuid from the the os package but I cant seem to find an equivalent for 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a `psutil` library. Try the [`uids`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.uids) function:

> uids()[source] The real, effective and saved user ids of this process
>   as a namedtuple. This is the same as `os.getresuid()` but can be used
>   for every process PID.
>
> Availability: UNIX

Comment: Is there any other workaround apart from using a psutil library? Like an built in function if it exists?